# how to write multiple Tuples from a list into single text file

Tags: list, python-2.7, text, tuples, extract

I have a List "m" of multiple tuples.

[image]

and each tuple has two strings ex. tuple 0 and tuple 1 in image.

I want to store all the **odd** numbered tuples(0,1,3....) in a **SINGLE** text file.

I tried following code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
    j = open('skills_list3.txt','w')
        mlen=len(m) #length of list
            mlen #mlen is 93


            index=1 #initiated with 1 so that only odd number of tuple extracted
            while index < mlen:
                sk=m[index]
                print (sk,file=j)
                index=index+2
```

I believe this is looping correctly through the list but I am not being able to know why are all tuples not being written to the txt file.

Program does not have any error.

Comment: Are you calling `.close()` on the file?

Comment: No. My ouput file is storing only the last record and not previous records.